# Bug in Wordpress plugin development, including my script; not possible to log in

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a plugin that through a shortcode allows to add a custom form that makes an ajax call. Unfortunately when I activate the plugin I can no longer log into the site.

I have attached my code:

Plugin definition `wrabbitc.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WRabbitC 0.2
...
*/
include_once( 'framework/wrabbit_shortcodes.php' );
if(!is_admin()) {
    add_shortcode( 'wrabbitc-sc', 'wrabbit_form_shortcode' );
}
```

`shortcodes.php`

```
<?php
function wrabbit_form_shortcode(){
    $_jsDir= plugins_url()."/wrabbitc/js/";
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'wrabbitc_formvalidation.js', $_jsDir.'wrabbitc_formvalidation.js', array('jquery'),'',true  );
    wp_enqueue_script('wrabbitc_formvalidation.js');
    wp_register_script( 'wrabbitc_ajaxcall.js', $_jsDir.'wrabbitc_ajaxcall.js', array('jquery'),'',true  );
    wp_enqueue_script('wrabbitc_ajaxcall.js');
    echo'
    <form id="form">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><Label>Name:</Label> <input type="text" name="name" required></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><Label>E-mail:</label> <input type="email" name="email" required></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><Label>Elaboration Type: <input type="text" name="proteins" placeholder="use add button" required id="proteins" required></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="btn"  onclick="aggiungiCodici();" value="ADD PDBs" class="wrap"/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>';
}
```

JS `wrabbitc_formvalidation`

```
function aggiungiCodici() {
    var codice = prompt("Please enter a code:", "");
    if (inputValidate(codice)) {
        var stringa = codice.toUpperCase() + "#";
        document.getElementById("proteins").value += stringa;
    } else {
        alert("pls enter a valid input");
    }
}
function inputValidate(codice) {
    var test = false;
    if (codice != "" && codice.length == 4) {
        var patt = /^.{0}[0-9].{1,}[a-z0-9A-Z]/;
        var res = patt.test(codice);
        test = res;
    }
    return test;
}
```

`wrabbit_wp_ajaxcall.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Variable to hold request
    var request;
    // Bind to the submit event of our form
    $("#form").submit(function (event) {
        // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
        event.preventDefault();
        // Abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(this);
        // Let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("text");
        // Serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
        // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
        // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        // Fire off the request to /form.php
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            data:{
              action:"wrabbitc_send_message",
              serializedData
            }
        });
        // Callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Log a message to the console
            alert(response);
            $("#form").hide();
        });
        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
            // Reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: [Check the log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and let us know what you find.

Comment: Also, an error message would be helpful. But maybe it's just because you echo the output in your shortcode instead of returning it?